# Synthetic carbon fixation pathways

Tags: photosynthesis, carbohydrates

Have there been carbon fixation pathways of, in particular, oxygen-producing bacteria, that have been replicated in the lab or at least the enzymes for the pathways have been successfully produced in the lab?

Comment: It is not just the enzymes. It is also the way they are arranged in the cell that dictates processes like photosynthesis.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I understand that..